# Add an image to browser enabled infopath form

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

Instead of digitally signing a form, is it possible for users to attach an image with their signature to the form in InfoPath 2007. The other users who are viewing the form should also be able to view the image and not as an attachment.

Form is browser enabled!

Answer (score 1):

Use a picture control and select "Included in the form" on the popup (instead of "as a link") and anything the user selects will show up directly in the form.

Note that using this as a signature does NOT ensure integrity/security. Any other user can remove that "signature" image and put their own (or put someone elses "signature" image in).

Comment: our client cant afford digital signature and cant we prevent other users from removing the image in infopath form? The current process involves converting the infopath form to pdf which the user takes a print copy, signs and uploads it again to the infopath form.

Comment: Picture control is disabled in browser enabled form

Comment: There are not many options for using a picture control in a browser enabled form (you shoud update your question to reflect that bit of info). See http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/6349.aspx for possible solutions.